# Best database for daily data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, database, csv

I'm currently working on a project where I'll be tracking daily data for around 30 fictive companies. Every company has a name, rank and balance. I want to track the rank and balance by saving the data everyday.
Now my question is how to store this data, should I use csv files, Json files, or a database? And if thats the case, wat database should I use as a beginner?
My project is build in javascript with nodejs and discordjs.

Comment: Why don't you give MongoDB a try? You can sign up to MongoDB Atlas (Cloud based) for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add timestamps in json, you should take a look at it!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using discordjs, If I am not wrong you would be fetching details using the discord api. So for data storage you can go for firebase either Realtime database or firestore database. It's super easy to implement and easily scalable and there are too lot of additional feature you will get along. This way your database will be easily fetchable from anywhere also.
Also you can anytime download your database into csv. Here is the the official [firebase node-js sdk documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node).